# What is an example of UFD such that a gcd of an infinite set does not exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a unique factorization domain and $S$ be an infinite subset of $R$. What would be an example of $R$, $S$ such that a gcd of $S$ does not exist in $R$?

That is, is there an infinite set $S$ such that there is no *least* principal ideal containing it? I think it is really hard to find this example..

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $R$. We prove that $\gcd S$ does exist.

If there exists a finite subset $S'\subset S$ with $\gcd S'=1$ then $\gcd S=1$.

Suppose $\gcd S'\ne1$ for any finite subset $S'\subset S$.

Fix an element $x\in S$. It has finitely many prime factors $p_1,\dots,p_r$, and one of these occurs in every other element of $S$. Otherwise, let $s_i\in S$ be such that $p_i\nmid s_i$. Then $s_1,\dots,s_r,x$ is a finite subset of $S$ with $\gcd=1$. Say $p_1\mid s$ for any $s\in S$. Now replace $S$ by $(1/p_1)S$ and continue the reasoning.

Comment: I'm not sure why $\gcd(s_1,\dots,s_r,x)=1$.

Comment: @egreg If not, then a prime divides all elements and such a prime is one of the $p_i$s.

Comment: OK, now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a bounded lattice where every element has only a finite number of predecessors. Then $L$ is $\land$-complete, in the sense that every subset has an infimum.

Indeed, if $S$ is a nonempty subset of $L$, fix $x\in S$. Then the set
$$
S'=\{x\land s:s\in S\}
$$
is finite, so its infimum exists and $\inf S'=\inf S$.

Now, let $L=R/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the “being associate” relation. Then $L$ is a lattice with respect to "is a divisor of” relation and every element has only a finite number of divisors.

Comment: Beautiful exposition.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \ldots (s_3,s_2,s_1) \mid (s_2,s_1)\mid s_1\, $ must stabilize (at $\,\gcd \{s_i\})$

Comment: This seems to assume $S$ is countable.

Comment: @lisyarus No, the point is that the divisibility relation in a UFD is well-founded: $s_1$ has a unique finite set of prime factors, and each proper factor in a divisibility chain removes at least one prime factor. Btw, it is more polite to ask for elaboration before downvoting, esp. for *hints*.